# NginX redirect not working properly

Tags: nginx, rewrite, http-status-code-404

I set up a redirecrt for NginX like this:

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?permalink=$1 last;
}
```

it is working fine for thousands of links but for few it does not

Some of the links which keep throwing 404 error are:

- profile/monico
- profile/hotstar
- profile/jongz
- profile/chico
- profile/nagz
- profile/mico
- profile/star

For thousands of other profile/* links it works fine.
I tried to access above profiles via:

```
index.php?permalink=profile/jongz
```

And it work fine.
So I assume there must be some misconfiguration or something which makes nginX to throw 404 - file not found error instead of proceeding to `rewrite` function.

Does those links contain some characters or character combinations which prevents nginX to rewrite link correctly?

Comment: Could these URIs point to static files or directories on the server?

Comment: I tried to create folder profile and file hotstar inside and it downloaded file so no 404 error. Actually google webmasters tool showed 2 new links in addition to previous:
profile/jellstar,
profile/az1914js

Comment: when i am looking at those links, isn't it possible that nginx is somehow looking for files with extensions ico, tar, gz?

Answer (score 0):

The following rule was the problem:

```
location ~* .(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
        etag on;
        if_modified_since exact;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}
```

Not sure why it is not picking dot at start of the expression. Does anyone know answer for this?

Comment: The `.` represents any character. If you want a literal `.` use backslash. E.g. `location ~* \.(js|jpg|jpeg|...`